# Unable to Mount NTFS partition "Not authorized"

Tags: mount, ntfs

This time I installed Ubuntu 11.10 in another partition rather than using wubi and making a virtual mount.

But now I'm not able to mount the other NTFS partitions and getting a message

`Unable to Mount <Partition Name>`
`Not Authorized`

Lol on not authorized.

Any advice on how can i access my NTFS partition.

Answer (score 1):

How are you starting your X session ? it's likely you didn't launch your session with proper command , e.g `ck-launch-session dbus-launch startxfce4` in `~/.xinitrc`;

if you intended to mount them at boot , edit your `/etc/fstab` , append:

`(Suppose to mount /dev/sda10 on /Misc)`

`/dev/sda10 /Misc ntfs defaults,uid=YOUR_UID 0 0`

Replace YOUR_UID with your uid , use `uid` command to find it out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have ntfs-3g and ntfsprogs installed. These are needed to access the NTFS files in Windows and lastly those files need to be shared from the windows machine with the correct permissions.

Comment: Ok cool.
Thanks for replying BlueXrider!

Well I got this tutorial from pendrivelinux
www.pendrivelinux.com/mounting-a-windows-xp-ntfs-partition-in-linux/

But then accidently it modified grub. I was not able to locate windows 7 on grub while reboot. Somehow the command

update-grub

got it running.But Now I see that I gotta re enter the command as super user to mount them every time I login. Is there any good tutorial out there to get a permanent solution?